# Swift UIImage full width of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have the UIImage like so:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

What I am trying to do it make the image full width of the screen, I have tried scaleToFill, scaleAspectFit and scaleAspectFill neither of them do anything...what am I doing wrong?

Here is my full code:

```
getLandGradingImage(image: imageData!) { result in
    let image = UIImage(data: result)

    if image != nil {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        //Add Image to view
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    } else {
        self.customAlert(title: "Error", message: "Unable to get images")
    }

}
```

Comment: There is too little information here to determine anything. Where are you giving the image view a size and position? What are you adding the image view to? Is this in a view controller? Which method are you adding it in? Are you using AutoLayout? How big is the image?

Comment: The image size is 1024, no I am not using AutoLayout, this is in a view controller

Comment: I suggest adding the UIImageView to the view BEFORE downloading the image. Use autolayout constraints to position it and size it. Then just set the image in the completion here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.frame = self.view.bounds
imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Still looks a little squished

Comment: use `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`

Answer (score 3):

You have to make your `UIImageView` frame the size of the area you want to fill.  You can do this by setting the frame explicitly or using auto-layout (recommended).

method 1:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = self.view.frame;
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//Add Image to view
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

method 2:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//Add Image to view
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": imageView]))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": imageView]))
```

Comment: AutoLayout VFL... old school.

Answer (score 1):

You want to manipulate the frame of the `UIImageView` and not the contentMode.

Try this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

imageView.frame = self.view.frame
imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: It works, but now the image looks squished, I am looking for away to have to full width and aspect the height

Comment: If you have this play with imageView.contentMode and look what you want for your needs

Comment: Just add `imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill` at the code suggested by Teetz